# Single quoted strings versus double quoted strings

Tags: php, string, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am really very confused about what is used to represent a string in PHP.

If we use double inverted commas, it too represents string and same if use single inverted commas so "avinash" or 'avinash'.

Which is a string?

Can you tell me about a good book to read PHP5 from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`'`) both represent strings. However, PHP doesn't treat them the same way.

In double quoted (`"`) strings, escape sequences and variable names are expanded. In single quotes (`'`) strings, they are not. The string is not expanded.

So, given the following:

```
$name = "Foo";
```

The following code...

```
$doubleQuotedString = "Hello $name.\nIt is nice to see you.";
echo $doubleQuotedString;
```

... will output this:

> `Hello Foo.`
>   `It is nice to see you.`

However, the following...

```
$singleQuotedString = 'Hello $name.\nIt is nice to see you.';
echo $singleQuotedString;
```

... will output this:

> `Hello $name.\nIt is nice to see you.`

For more information, you can read the following documentation page on strings.

> [PHP Documentation: Strings](http://php.net/types.string)

Comment: hey thanks....but could you advice me some book....bcoz problems of this sort keep cropping up

Comment: @avinash: The PHP Documentation cannot be clearer on the subject. Read the Language reference section.